# Checkboxes disappearing or glitching on Chrome

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a problem with checkboxes on my website.

I have this code that creates checkboxes :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="portlet light">
    <div class="form-group form-md-checkboxes">
        <div class="md-checkbox-list liste_personnes">
        <?php

        foreach ($users as $value){

            echo "<div class=\"md-checkbox\" style=\"overflow:hidden;\">";
            echo "<input id=\"usersbox[".$value->id_user."]\" name=\"usersbox[".$value->id_user."]\" groups=\"".$value->groups."\" class=\"md-check users\" type=\"checkbox\">";
            echo "<label for=\"usersbox[".$value->id_user."]\">";
            echo "<span class=\"inc\"></span>";
            echo "<span class=\"check\"></span>";
            echo "<span class=\"box\"></span>";
            echo '<div id="gauche">'.$value->name. ' '.$value->firstname.'</div>';
            //echo '<div id="droite">'.$value->communication.'</div>';
            echo "</label>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That way, it works on Firefox and IE. I had to put the overflow:hidden to make it work on IE. If I delete de overflow:hidden, I get my checks to go on two columns like this (on IE):
[image]

And on chrome :

[image]

So whatever I did, it didn't work on Chrome, it works on IE if I let the overflow:hidden, and it works everytime on Firefox.

I have this piece of css that I added :

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
.liste_personnes{
-webkit-columns: 3 auto;
-moz-columns: 3 auto;
columns: 3 auto;
```

}

Do you have any idea what's causing this trouble ? Should I change my checkbox implementation ?